# mongoose only saves one of several users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, I've got this schema:

```
var FileSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    owner: String,
    processed: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserFile', FileSchema);
```

that I'm trying to save on a certain function as follows:

```
var newFile = new UserFile();

  newFile.owner    = decoded.email;
  newFile.name = req.file.originalname;
  newFile.processed = false;

  // save the file
  newFile.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
          throw err;
  });
```

Yet when I check the database, the document is saved only with the `owner` and `processed` fields. The field called `name` doesn't appear.

If I `console.log` the variable `req.file.originalname` , I get the correct result, so it's not null (?). Why is it not saving then?

Comment: Hello, your code looks normal I think problem in req.file.originalname variable. Try do it like this 'newFile.name = "TestName";' and see result.

Comment: @sergaros a plain string is saved well. Req.file.originalname comes from a file uploaded, but I can console. Log it just fine. Why can't I save it then?

Comment: Maybe it's not string type? try " typeof(req.file.originalname);"

Comment: @Sergaros nope, type string.

Comment: @Sergaros I just noticed I have the following warning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html  . Could that have something to do with by problem?

Comment: Very strange, So if you log it  -  console.log(req.file.originalname);  newFile.name = req.file.originalname; it's output correct value? Maybe you need drop your database

Comment: About warning just add that string "mongoose.Promise = Promise;" in your mongoose module before "mongoose.connect(..."

Comment: @Sergaros I've got no idea why, but dropping the database solved the issue. Thanks!